# How to find tooltip control

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

How do I find a tooltip control for any control in Winform with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use the following :

```
string text = toolTip1.GetToolTip(yourControl);
```

This gives you the text on the tooltip for that control.

You can set the text of a certain tooltip for your control like this:

```
toolTip2.SetToolTip(yourControl, "My tooltip text");
```